# What are the valid data types for API Blueprint?

Tags: apiblueprint

I am just wondering exactly what the valid data types are when working with API Blueprints?

The [documentation](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md) seems unclear to me. More specifically, it says:

> type is the optional parameter type as expected by the API (e.g. "number", "string", "boolean"). "string" is the default.

Does this mean:

1. Only "number", "string" and "boolean" are valid?
2. It is expecting [JSON primitive types](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor8)?
3. Other?

Comment: Can you clarify? The documentation you reference is for URL parameters, which have nothing to do with JSON. They must at least be url safe strings, but you can specify if the parameter is some other type for the sake of documentation.

Comment: Apologies I subsequently realised we were using other packages to come up with a mock server. My question (now answered internally) is for later in our specific pipeline, not API Blueprint. Cheers.

Comment: Ehhh... This remains a valid question! `base type 'binary' is not defined in the document` — how do I define a bytestring parameter?.. Where's the reference of available types? I need to know.